# Can I pull a value from another table using EF without defining a new Entity?

Tags: entity-framework

I've got two tables Jobs and JobGroups.  Jobs looks like this:

```
int Id  (PK)
varchar(30) Description
int GroupId  (FK)
```

JobGroups looks like this

```
int Id  (PK)
varchar(30) GroupName
```

The only way I would know to map this using EF and fluent api is to define the following classes:

```
public class Job
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public int GroupId {get; set;}
   public JobGroup Group {get; set;}

   //what I would rather see is this
   public string GroupName {get; set;}
}

public class JobGroup
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasKey(j => j.Id).HasRequired(j => j.JobGroup).WithMany();
```

However, all I want is the JobGroup Name.  Is there any way to simply pull the name from the JobGroups table without having to have the JobGroup class?  Almost like entity splitting except that the Job Id would not exist in the JobGroups table.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - Entity framework works with entities and entities must be mapped - the mapping tells EF how to generate SQL to query the database. If you want to get some column from unmapped table you must write your own SQL.

If you want to map `Job` directly with `JobGroup.Name` instead of `JobGroupId` you must create a database view because the result of such mapping is not an entity - it is a projection and the only available mapped projections in EF code first are database views. Such projection is also read only because EF doesn't know how to get the `Id` of the `JobGroup` back to correctly persist a `Job` (it doesn't know how the view created it).